# Center align title in toolbar with navigation icon set programatically in Android app?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am using a toolbar as my action bar in my activity and i want to center align the title. I am setting a navigation icon as well and the title is aligning a bit right to the center. It is treating the navigation icon as a different part and aligning center based on the remaining width. Here is my toolbar xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlecontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titlesupport"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is how i am setting the toolbar and the title in my activity oncreate

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
TextView title = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText("MY TITLE");
```

I am sure it is something very basic that i am missing but i have looked at all the answers and tried lots of settings with no result.

**EDIT I have also removed the settings menu icon from the menu_main and it is now blank**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      tools:context=".MainActivity">
</menu>
```

Answer (score 4):

For those, who still stuck when having only navigation icon (no menu icon)

I use `setContentInsetsAbsolute` to create an content insets on the right to be the same width as the left using

```
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,toolbar.getContentInsetStartWithNavigation());
```

Also set this after you have included the navigation icon if you included it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the gravity properties for your text view. 
Change **width of TextView to match_parent and add gravity to center.** Also change width of your linear layout to match_parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titlecontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titlesupport"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Still doesnt work. Please check the edit, i have also removed the action settings menu icon. if i place that item then your solution is working but i need that removed

Comment: do you actually need toolbar..?? why can't you try  replacing your toolbar with LinearLayout only with two buttons on sides and title in the center.?

Comment: I am using some functionalities of the toolbar in some child fragments to navigate up so i need it

Comment: then you  can  have the menu at the right side. do you want menu to show or hide ? If you do so, then the title will be aligned neatly

Answer (score -3):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar""
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Test Alignment"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:id="@+id/title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. Please check the edit, i have also removed the action settings menu icon. if i place that item then your solution is working but i need that removed